# Update CustomField using metadata api

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

When i am trying to update any standard field, it is working:

```
MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Account.phone';
customField.label = 'testing';
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
```

But when i try to update a custom field, it throws an error, asking to give additional parameters (like, type, length if its a Text type field):

```
MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Account.Active__c';
customField.label = 'testing';
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks @Keith, I tried readmetadata also, but I am getting null in the result.

```
MetadataService.IReadResult test = service.readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { 'Account.Active__c'});
customField = (MetadataService.CustomField)test.getRecords()[0];
customField.label = 'testing';
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
```

When i try to debug test.getRecords()[0] -- its attributes like :

```
records=(CustomField:[Metadata.fullName=null, apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), caseSensitive=null,
```

an so on..

Comment: Suggest you `readMetadata`, modify, then `updateMetadata` to work around the problem.

Comment: @KeithC - Please see updated question.. I also tried readMetadata..but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Standard fields don't have much metadata, usually just the fullname and type. Even standard picklist values are pretty sparse.

Custom fields however have lots of metadata and you must have that information for an update. You mentioned the length parameter for a text field. Yep, you need all that stuff.

The metadata channel does not merge Custom Fields they are asset types and you need all the parameters. Hope that helps.