# Custom field update API

Tags: rest-api, custom-field, tooling-api

I am working in a sandbox, and using the Tooling API. I need to update the metadata of the custom field in Salesforce, but I am unable to do so. For this I am trying to work on the PATCH method. Below is the postman request i have used to update the custom field metadata:

Method:

```
PATCH
```

URL:

```
https://cs21.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/customfieldid
```

HEADERS:

```
Authorization : Bearer TOken
Content-Type : application/json
```

Body:

```
{

"FullName":"Contact.AFMO_Account__c",
"Metadata":
{
"description": "test"
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving when making this request from postman?

Comment: Your only tag is community, are you trying to do this as an unregistered user, or a user without full API privileges?

Comment: I am sucessfully geting data when i am using  this url "https://cs21.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N3600000PSxiL" with Get request but while using patch request to update custom fiels I am facing issue

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me as a PATCH via [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php):

`/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N70000002kxvG`

```
{
  "Metadata" : {
    "description" : "Test Number with Length 8 and 2 decimal places",
    "label" : "TestNumber",
    "type" : "Number",
    "precision" : 10,
    "scale" : 2
  },
  "FullName" : "Account.DFB__TestNumber__c"
}
```

I haven't gone through all the permutations, but if you take away fields such as `precision` you start getting errors such as:

> [ {
>     "message" : "Must specify 'precision' for a CustomField of type Number",
>     "errorCode" : "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
>     "fields" : [ ]
>   } ]

Comment: I've observed similar effects in DX, of which I'm hoping to get a few of them resolved or at least logged as bugs with the DX team tomorrow.

Comment: @sfdcfox It does seem odd that I can't patch the description in isolation.

Comment: Can we do this by metadata Api or we can update custom field by Metadata Api?If yes please can you please share  some example

Comment: @VanshikaJoshi Yes, you should be able to update a CustomField via Metadata API. That is probably best handled in a separate question. See [Update CustomField using metadata api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/128966/102)

Comment: hi i want to update the lookup filter with custom field   , i want to active and deactivate the that field of lookup filter for custom field , this lookup filter can able to view under metadata of the custom field , but not able to update (active/deactivate) with tooling patch api , so kindly suggest me , how i can do this

Comment: hi i want to update the lookup type custom field(Active/Deactive that filter) ,I am able to view this field by metadata Api , but not able to update (active/deactivate) with tooling patch api , so kindly suggest me , how i can do this?

Comment: Hi @VanshikaJoshi, I'd suggest raising a new question to handle this refined scenario. Put the details of what specifically you are aiming to achieve, what you have tried, and how it is failing. Generally the questions and answers on this site aren't changed to something different. It may be that the API required to update the lookup filter is significantly different to just changing the description.

Comment: "lookupFilter": {
            "booleanFilter": null,
            "filterItems": [
                {
                    "field": "Account.RecordTypeId",
                    "operation": "equals",
                    "value": "WV AFMO Account Record Type",
                    "valueField": null
                }
            ],
            "active": true,
            "description": null,
            "errorMessage": null,
            "infoMessage": null,
            "isOptional": false
        } i want to update this filetr field into contact object