# Unable to add CustomField to CustomObject Python API Simple Salesforce

Tags: metadata-api, python, simple-salesforce

When trying to UPDATE CustomObject with newly added custom field, I get this error message:
 `TestCustomObject__c.AccountNumber_NEW__c: (INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, In field: fullName - no CustomField named TestCustomObject__c.AccountNumber_NEW__c found)`

Sample code looks like this:

```
custom_object = mdapi.CustomObject.read(custom_object_fullname)
custom_field = mdapi.CustomField(
                        fullName="AccountNumber_NEW__c", description="Not used"
                    )
                    new_fields = [custom_field]
custom_object.fields += new_fields
mdapi.CustomObject.update(custom_object)
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: example: https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/542

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. The creation of Custom Object with Custom Fields works fine. But the update for some reason does not, so this doesn't address my issue.

Comment: You posted [your question](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/602) on GH, that's the right place to ask. As an alternative, you can try modifying the field via [Tooling API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217545/custom-field-update-api), simple-salesforce supports it

Comment: Tooling API is working for me, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217545/custom-field-update-api